# Getting Invalid App ID error while integrating with Facebook although my App ID is correct

Tags: php, facebook, sdk

Getting Invalid App ID error while integrating login with Facebook. I have exactly copied the code given on following Facebook page by replacing my App ID & Secret.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/php/howto/example_facebook_login/5.0.0

I have tested the App ID by using http://graph.facebook.com/1486873724938940 and it's giving me app details correctly.

Following is the error I am getting on the screen after I click the login button.

> Invalid App ID: {1486873724938940}

Comment: Does your app secret match/belong to your app-id?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It was a very silly mistake but I am writing the answer for just in case some other newbie like me faces the same issue.

The code given by Facebook which I was using as reference went like:
'app_id' => '{app-id}'

Herein I was only replacing the app-id and not the curly brackets, therefore, was facing the issue.

What I was doing
'app_id' => '{1486873724938940}'

What I was supposed to be doing
'app_id' => '1486873724938940'